# Prove that $6 | (a+b+c)$ if and only if $6 | (a^3 + b^3 +c^3).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have tried the question but not sure if my solution is correct or not...
My try..

\begin{align}a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = (a+b+c)^3 - 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\end{align}

So , if

\begin{align}6 |(a^3 + b^3 + c^3)\end{align}

Then,

\begin{align}6 | [(a+b+c)^3 - 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)]\end{align}

So, also

\begin{align}6 | (a+b+c)^3\end{align}

\begin{align}6 | (a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c)\end{align}

So,

\begin{align}6|(a+b+c)\end{align}

Is my solution correct ?

Comment: I think 6 | [(a+b+c)^3 - 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)] doesn’t mean 6 | (a+b+c)^3 and 6 | (a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c).They might just had the same remainder when divided by 6.

Comment: Oh yes, that's what I didn't thought of...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got

> Then,
>
> 6 | [(a+b+c)^3 - 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)]
>
> So, also
>
> 6 | (a+b+c)^3
>
> 6 | (a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c)

As [Iris](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/656794/iris)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3554694/prove-that-6-abc-if-and-only-if-6-a3-b3-c3/3554700#comment7309764_3554694) says, because $6$ divides the first expression of $(a+b+c)^3 - 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$ doesn't mean it divides the first term, i.e., $(a+b+c)^3$ and then a different expression of $(a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c)$.

Instead, here is a simpler way. Note that odd integers cubed are odd & even integers cubed are even, so for all integers $n$ you have

$$n^3 \equiv n \pmod 2 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Also, as $3$ is prime, then by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), for all integers $n$,

$$n^3 \equiv n \pmod 3 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime, you can put these together to get

$$n^3 \equiv n \pmod 6 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Thus, you get

$$a + b + c \equiv a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \pmod 6 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

As such,

$$a + b + c \equiv 0 \pmod 6 \iff a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \equiv 0 \pmod 6 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your incorrect solution has been pointed out by Iris in the comments.

\begin{align}
&(a^3+b^3+c^3) - (a+b+c)  = (a^3 - a) + (b^3-b) + (c^3-c) \\ &\quad \quad \ = (a-1)a(a+1) + (b-1)b(b+1) + (c-1)c(c+1)
\end{align}

The set of terms in $(a-1)a(a+1)$ contains at least one multiple of $2$ and one multiple of $3$ by the pigeonhole principle. By coprimality of $2,3$, each such number is a multiple of $6$. So $(a^3+b^3+c^3) - (a+b+c)$ is a multiple of $6$ : if one is divisible by $6$, so is the other.

Answer (score 0):

$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3-3(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)$

At least one pair from $(a+b) , (b+c)  , (a+c)$ is even number.

Therefore, $6 | 3(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)$. Consequently,

$a^3+b^3+c^3 \equiv (a+b+c)^3 \mod{6}$

$a^3+b^3+c^3 \equiv a+b+c \mod{6}$